# If $S=1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}\cdots$, then what is $\lfloor S \rfloor$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If 
>   $$S=1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}\cdots$$ 
>   then $$\lfloor S \rfloor  = \text{?}$$

What I tried:

I know that 
$$S=1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\cdots=\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}\approx 1.1$$
then $\lfloor S \rfloor =1$.

But how do I find with inequality? Please have a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(k-1)^3}-\frac1{k^3}
&=\frac{3k^2-3k+1}{k^3(k-1)^3}\\
&\gt\frac{3k^2-3k}{k^3(k-1)^3}\\
&=\frac3{k^2(k-1)^2}\\
&\gt\frac3{k^4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^4}
&\lt\frac13\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{(k-1)^3}-\frac1{k^3}\right)\\
&=\frac1{3(n-1)^3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\frac{1}{k^4}=\int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{1}{k^4}\,dx\le \int_{k-1}^k\frac{1}{x^4}\,dx$$

Therefore, $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k^4}\le \sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^k\frac{1}{x^4}\,dx=\int_1^n \frac{1}{x^4}\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\left[1-\frac{1}{n^3}\right]$$

Taking limit as $n\to\infty$, we get $$\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4}\le \frac{1}{3}$$

Hence we can say that $$ 1\le S\le 1+\frac{1}{3}$$